# Level shifting using MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, uart, level-shifting

I am trying to shift the UART voltages of a 1.8 V device to 3.3 V.

I have implemented the following circuit using the RYC002N05 MOSFET:

[image]

After checking the output signal with an oscilloscope, I saw that it only goes up to around 1.5 V on the 3.3 V side (3.3V - 1.8V coincidentally?). The input signal looks fine.

[image: oscilloscope photo]

(input signal on the bottom, output on the top)

I understand that the capacitances of the MOSFET influences the edges of the signal but I do not understand why it only goes up to 1.5 V (UART running at 9600 baud.)

**Solution**:
I have found the problem. There is some design variant of my PCB that has a 100nF capacitor from OUTPUT to GND (the signal is something else in that variant) and it was fitted by mistake. I removed it and the signals look perfect!

Comment: The FETs are not fast enough. If you record the last bit during communication before the signals goes up to 5V you will measure the time the signal needs. In my setup with a BSS138 it took 2ms, so communication up to 500 kHz would be ok. Your BAUD rate of 9600 is much slower so is it possible that your FET is that much slower, too?

Comment: The 50 ohms resistor value on the right is suspicious. It should be a couple kOhms as a pullup. But the trace looks like the resistor is way higher, which slows it down. Can you check what resistor is actually soldered on the board?

Comment: @bobflux Oh, yes it should be 10k as well, it was the default value when creating the schematic. I will update the question

Comment: 10k on the 1V8 side is not useful as the signal is an output. 10k on the 3V3 side is way too high for fast edges. I don't suggest using FET level shifter for UART.

Comment: @celeryperson, can I suggest that you post your solution as an official answer. I think it would be beneficial to others who may need the information.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem. There is some design variant of my PCB that has a 100 nF capacitor from OUTPUT to GND (the signal is something else in that variant) and it was fitted by mistake. I removed it and the signals look perfect!